# advice about the PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Im working on application design using Qt Design. the design completed so now i want to connect it with Python 3.6.4 using pycharm. and import PyQt5. i already installed PyQt5 as you can see.

> PS C:\Users\Tariq> pip install pyqt5
>   Requirement already satisfied :pyqt5 in
>   c:\users\tariq\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   Requirement already satisfied: sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 in
>   c:\users\tariq\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from pyqt5)

also i installed PyQt5 inside pycharm as you can see in the picture. 
[**Press enter to show the image that PyQt5 installed inside pycharm**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06MS1.png)

My Problem that the PyQt5 unknown for pycharm and this error appear

> ```
> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*  
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5
> ```

'

Comment: Any update plz ,,,

Comment: typo: change `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*` to `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`

Answer (score 1):

The way that has always worked for me is below.

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe due to the way you set up your environment variable add this `c:\Python3*\Script`,`C:\Python3*\Lib\site-packages\`, and `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\` in your environmental path, hope it works. '*` is the version of python e.g Python34